# Projecting Rasters, shift to the north. Can i correct it?

Tags: r, gis, r-raster, map-projections

I would like to project one raster onto another and while doing so I think the values are changing their position "to the north".

Is this an expected behavior?

I was hoping to create a longlat raster to use it for lookups and GeoJSON generation.

Strangely (or maybe expected, I don't know) resulting GeoJSON positions are shifted (what feels like 10km) to the north.

Do I have a logical mistake somewhere?

This is an example:

```
x <- raster(ncol=900, nrow=900)
x_proj <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.3142451802 +to_meter=1000 +no_defs "
proj <- CRS(x_proj)
extent(x) <- extent(-523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645)
projection(x) <- x_proj
x[seq(450,455),seq(1,900)]<-1

new_raster<-raster(ncols=900,nrows=900)
new_raster_crs<- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +zone=34 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84"
new_raster_proj <- CRS(new_raster_crs)
extent(new_raster) <- extent(3.5889,14.6209, 47.0705, 54.7405)
projection(new_raster) <- new_raster_proj
new_raster<-projectRaster(x,new_raster,method = "bilinear")
```

Plot of raster `x`

[image: Plot of Raster x]

Plot of Raster `new_raster`

[image: Plot of Raster new_raster]

Is there something I could to with source/dest raster to create a "true" longlat lookup / GeoJSON possibility?

Is there a mistake somewhere ?

Can i maybe change +y_0=0 value to correct this?

If thats the case how can I get the exact value of shift?

Currently I only see the change visually.

Comment: I think you are more likely to get answers about projections-related stuff at [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I postet it there now too. If i get an answer i would post it here too.

Comment: Could you add what projection you're trying to reproject **from**? (I'm getting a warning "Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition", so there might be some flaw in the definition (`"+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90  ... "`) already.

Comment: Im trying to project from raster (x). That raster is created from Radolan DWD radar image and the proj string which is provided is all i have.

Comment: Apparently, RADOLAN imagery is delivered in (arctic) polar stereographic projection ( https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/recent/asc/BESCHREIBUNG_gridsgermany-hourly-radolan-recent-asc_de.pdf ) used for higher latitudes than the northern border of your extent (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/map/projections/polar-stereographic.htm ).

Comment: `+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189
+x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370040 +b=6370040 +to_meter=1000 +no_defs`, note spherical integers for +a, +b [RADOLIN](https://docs.wradlib.org/en/stable/notebooks/radolan/radolan_grid.html)

Comment: @Chris i do use those values  furthermore your suggestion produces the same warnings: Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded ellps unknown in Proj4 definition: +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6370040 +units=km +no_defs +type=crs
2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum unknown in Proj4 definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is as expected. Map projections distort (at least one of) shape, size, distance, and direction. In this case, you observe a change in shape.

You do make a mistake here:

```
new_raster_crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +zone=34 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84"
```

"zone" is only relevant for the "UTM" coordinate reference system (and perhaps others), and if you define a datum, you should not also define an ellipsoid. So it should be

```
new_raster_crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
```

But it seems that the other parts you add are simply ignored.

Another mistake is that you still use `raster`, as it has been replaced by `terra`. With `terra` it goes like this:

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(ncol=900, nrow=900, ext=c(-523.4622, 376.5378, -4658.645, -3758.645),
    crs="+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=90 +lon_0=10 +k=0.93301270189 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.3142451802 +to_meter=1000 +no_defs")
    
x[seq(450,455),seq(1,900)]<-1

y <- rast(ncols=900, nrows=900, ext= c(3.5889,14.6209, 47.0705, 54.7405), crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

z <- project(x, y)
plot(z)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding terra. I was not aware of that. I switched to it. So if there is a shift to the north, is it not possible to calculate it and adjust it by false north ?

Comment: There is no "shift to the north"; or I do not understand what you mean by that. All we see is a change in the shape of a line (as represented by the raster); but that is not unexpected. Or is there is something else you see?

Comment: I found this description to the origin projection : https://maps.dwd.de/geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.demo.SRSDescriptionPage?2&code=EPSG:1000001   but it seems to fit with my proj string or do i not see a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I cannot respond because it is not clear what you mean by "shift to the north"; or why you believe this is happening (what it is that you observe that makes you think that).